# How do we persist a `source bash_profile` command outside of a ruby script?

Tags: ruby, shell, bash

What we're trying to do is call `source bash_profile` to reload a bash_profile file. The script grabs a person's bash_profile and load it onto a person's computer. The problem is that the `source bash_profile` won't persist outside the ruby script. After the script ends, the terminal looks the same as it did before. How can we make it so that `source bash_profile` persists outside the ruby script?

Answer (score 0):

The `bash_profile` usually modifies the bash environment (installing functions, aliases, variables, readline bindings, etc.), and there is really no way to modify the environment of a parent bash process.

So the best you can do is end the ruby script by [`exec`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-exec)ing a new bash, specifying the `-l` (or `--login`) option to make it a [login shell](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-login-shell) so that it will start by sourcing `bash_profile`. (You can also do this by making the first character of argument `-`, usually by setting it to `-bash`.)

If you have control over the way the ruby script is initiated, you might be able to cause it to be [`exec`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-exec)ed, in order that it replaces the parent bash process. That will make for a cleaner process tree.